# Page events – only past events returned when using API v2.4+

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to fetch all events for a given page. I used to do it by simply requesting  `/{pageID}/events`. However in Facebook Graph API 2.4 and 2.5 only events from the past are returned.

Compare these two requests: [Api v 2.4](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=TheGarageHighbury%2Fevents%3Ffields%3Dstart_time&version=v2.4) vs [Api v 2.3](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=TheGarageHighbury%2Fevents%3Ffields%3Dstart_time&version=v2.3).

Api 2.4 returns the newest event dated `2016-03-07T17:00:00+0000` while Api 2.3 `2016-04-29T22:00:00+0100`.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes mentions a change regarding the order in which events are returned, but it says that’s only for `{user-id}/events`. // Suggest you file a bug report, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, this was a bug in Facebook API. I reported it and Facebook confirmed.

However, there's a fix which can be applied on the client side before Facebook engineers manage to fix this. All you need to do is add `since=today` parameter to the request. This results in fetching only future events.